# Google classic line chart upper space

Tags: javascript, charts, line, linechart

I am using [google line chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) in my project. I need to add some space between the highest value and the top bar.

I want to make it look like google url shortener statistics. 
I am linking to two images, the first one is my project's current status screenshot and the second one is google url shortener statistics screenshot. Hope you will understand what I need.

[My project's google line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk8dq.png). I need some space between the highest value and the top bar.

Google url shortener statistics [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqkAK.png). It has some space between the highest value and the top bar.

Comment: here it is https://jsfiddle.net/ohidul/922g1kzv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your options:

```
vAxis: {
    viewWindow:{
        max:6,
        min:0
    },
    ticks: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
},
```

Updated your [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/922g1kzv/3/).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set `alignment-baseline` to `hanging` on the svg `text` elements:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart5, 'ready', function() {
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#chart_div text[text-anchor=end]'))
            .forEach(function(element) {
                 element.setAttribute('alignment-baseline', 'hanging');
             });
});
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/922g1kzv/1/**